# IOS/Objective-C: Display uilabelview on two lines

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am having trouble getting a uilabelview to always display on two lines.  When the page first loads, the text only uses one line and is truncated.  Once you load another view controller on top of it--for example an edit VC and then cancel the second VC, the label does flow to two lines which is what I want.  However, I cannot get it to do first time.

Can anyone suggest what is issue?  What could be different between the VC at first and then after you have shown and canceled another VC on top of it.

The label is created in storyboard.  It is reference in code in viewwillappear as follows:

```
_myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
     NSString *nameToDisplay = _myItem.name;
     [_myLabel sizeToFit];
    [_myLabel setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Maybe try popping that code in viewdidload and seeing the result.

Comment: Try calling setNeedsLayout and layoutIfNeeded on the parent view instead of setNeedsDisplay on the label.

Comment: No change.  It still shows the second line after you launch and close a 2nd view controller but only one line truncated when it first loads.

Comment: Putting it in view did load worked.  Can't say why since viewwillappear was definitely getting called, but glad!